# How to find direction of velocity V2 to reach an object travelling at velocity V1, such that it takes least time?

Tags: physics, calculus-of-variations

If an object A is currently at point P1 moving with constant velocity V1,
and there is another object, object B which currently at point P2 which can move with velocity v2, then what should be the direction of velocity vector V2, so that it reaches in minimum time possible?

#### glossary

- P1,P2 - position vector of object A & object B respectively
- V1,V2 - velocity vector of object A & object B respectively
- v1,v2 - magnitude of V1 & V2 respectively

The question is with respect to 2D motion, from top view, no gravity or other force.

#### Analogy

Consider a ball moving on ground with constant speed and I too have a ball which I can throw at a fixed speed. What should be the direction to reach the ball?

Comment: Perhaps better to post this at the phsyics or math exchange?

Comment: Wherever this belongs, proper formulation and spelling / capitalization are always useful to help readers along.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about the software *Mathematica*.

Comment: Oh i thought this exchange was for something like this.... Where should i post it? Physics or math?

Comment: For these types of problems, the best is to use relative velocity of one object wrt another.

Comment: The question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346403/intersection-of-two-moving-objects is very similar and the answers are easily applied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation in the problem statement seems misleading to me.
We are given symbols $P_1,$ $P_2,$ $V_1,$ $V_2,$ $v_1,$ and $v_2,$
seemingly describing objects $1$ and $2$ in a completely symmetric fashion,
whereas the problem statement actually *is not symmetric.*

The problem statement implies that $P_1,$ $P_2,$ $V_1,$ $v_1,$ and $v_2$
are all known, with $v_1 = \lVert V_1\rVert.$
The *unknown* entity is $V_2$; we have the constraint that 
$\lVert V_2\rVert = v_2,$ but as long as that constraint is satisfied,
we can choose the direction of $V_2$ freely.

The mathematics of finding a suitable direction for $V_2$ were thoroughly hashed out in the answers to [Intersection of two moving objects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346403/intersection-of-two-moving-objects).
There is [an algebraic treatment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1346458)
which concludes with an equation that the angle $\phi$ (the direction of vector $V_2$) must meet in order to make Object $2$ meet Object $1.$
There are at most two solutions of the equation, but in some cases a solution of the equation gives a value of $\phi$ that causes Object $2$ to move *away* from Object $1$ (so they will never meet), while in other cases there are two values of $\phi$ that would cause the objects to meet, although only one of those values can be the one that makes them meet in the minimum possible time.

I find a geometric approach gives me more insight on the problem;
in particular, once the geometry of the problem has been set up
in this way
(see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1346508)
or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1346509))
it immediately gives us the equation
$$
v_2 \cos \phi = -v_1 \cos\theta,
$$
where $\phi$ is the angle between $V_2$ and the line $P_2P_1$
and $\theta$ is the angle between $V_1$ and the line $P_2P_1,$
measuring both angles counterclockwise.
(The algebraic treatment comes to an equivalent conclusion.)
Another way to say this is:

> In order for the two objects to meet, the component of $V_2$ perpendicular to the line between the objects must exactly cancel the component of $V_1$ perpendicular to the line between the objects.

This condition is necessary but *not sufficient* to solve the problem.
A condition that is both necessary *and* sufficient is:

> The vector $V_2 - V_1$ must point in the direction from $P_2$ to $P_1.$

Geometrically, we can construct representations of all possible vectors of the form $V_2 - V_1$ (given that $V_1$ is fixed and the magnitude but not the direction of $V_2$ is fixed)
by drawing the vector $-V_1$ and then drawing a circle of radius $v_2$
around the tip of $V_1.$
We can then represent $V_2 - V_1$ by placing its tail at the tail of
$-V_1$ and its head at any point on the circle; the direction from the center of the circle to the chosen point is the direction of $V_2.$

The diagram in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1346508)
shows the case where $v_1 > v_2$ but where it is still possible to make the objects meet.
In this case the circle intersects the line $P_1P_2$ in two places,
giving two possible choices of a vector $V_2$ that will cause the objects to meet.
The choice that causes the objects to meet in the minimum possible time is the choice for which the magnitude of $V_2 - V_1$ is larger.
(In the diagram in the linked answer, that vector is $CG.$)

When $v_1 > v_2,$ it can also happen that there is no solution to the problem; object $2$ can only "catch" object $1$ if object $1$ is initially reducing its distance to object $2$ quickly enough.

When $v_2 \geq v_1,$ there is always a solution but only one solution
for $V_2$ that allows object $2$ to "catch" object $1,$
so of course that is also the minimum-time solution.
The solution is shown graphically in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1346509).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
pos1 = {p1x, p1y} + {v1x, v1y}*t;
pos2 = {v2x, v2y}*t;

Solve[{pos1 == pos2, v2x^2 + v2y^2 == v2^2}, {v2x, v2y, t}]
```

Comment: Seams very simple with mathematica... But i needed to solve it without mathematica. Posted the question in the wrong exchange ...